# I AM Trying to connect my Website with Remix Ethereum IDE and getting Error { (index):85 Uncaught TypeError: CoursetroContract.at is not a function}

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, web3-providers

'''

Document

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

```
    <h1>Coursetro Instructor</h1>

    <h2 id="instructor"></h2>

    <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text">

    <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Age</label>
    <input id="age" type="text">

    <button id="button">Update Instructor</button>


</div>



<script>

   if (typeof web3 !=='undefined') {

web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

} else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"));
}

web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

var CoursetroContract = new web3.eth.Contract([
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "_fName",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "_age",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "setInstructor",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "getInstructor",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
}
]);
var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('0x5c6479Be2eD8cA2C6E1bbBDa86Aa60190923d72F');
    
console.log(Coursetro);
    Coursetro.getInstructor(function(error, result){
        if(!error)
            {
                $("#instructor").html(result[0]+' ('+result[1]+' years old)');
                console.log(result);
            }
        else
            console.error(error);
    });

    $("#button").click(function() {
        Coursetro.setInstructor($("#name").val(), $("#age").val());
    });
</script>
```

'''

[image: this is the error I was getting, help me to complete this]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how `.at(addr)` works in front-end but you can connect to an already deployed contract in the following way using `web3`:

```
myContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(
  contractABI,
  contractDeployedAddress
);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: yes,I Deployed my smart contract in remix ide and i took AbI and Contract address and placed in the html code

Comment: I hope its working fine.

Comment: it doesn't work,getting error{  await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules}

Comment: Remove await in that case, updated my code.

Comment: would you help me with the "set" funtion from my code?